# java proxy server halting https requests after receiving OCSP response

Tags: java, https, proxy, handshake

i am writing a Proxy server in java (think of academic interest), and am successful in getting it serve HTTP requests quite well. however, i am facing issues with HTTPS requests although i did as specified in the document : http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt

i.e. send the below message :

HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established\r\n
Proxy-Host: ProxyServer/1.0\r\n
\r\n\r\n

to the client after establishing connection to the actual HTTPS Server

and then start pumping the data to and fro between the client and the server.

i was able to get the handshake done, and the browser verify the certificates of the server using ocsp request-response cycle. but after successfully receiving ocsp response, the browser is sitting idle, and is not requesting the actual content from the HTTPS server. i think the request-response cycle is deemed ended by the browser after this stage.

can someone please explain me what am i doing wrong, and why did the browser think that the proxy is interrupting its workflow?

Comment: Do you see `ChangeCipherSpec` messages in the client-side captures? What happens if you disable OCSP in your browser, does the SSL handshake get any further?

Comment: this is the cycle when ocsp was enabled :

(1) the browser made a request (encryped), the server responded (encrypted + some legible text regarding the certificate authorities and the subject details)

(2) the browser made a POST request to the CA's ocsp gateway (content encrypted), and the ocsp gateway responded back (encrypted plus some certificate subject details)

(3) did not happen

when ocsp is disabled, step 2 did not happen, but the process halted after step 1.

Comment: i noticed that the client hello and server hello are happening but the client is not exchanging its key. not sure why it stops in the middle

Comment: after the server key (certificate) exchange, the browser is not exchanging its key and halting the flow.

but after this i noticed that the client is reissuing client hello and the above 3 steps follow again, for 3 or 4 times and ends up with no error to the proxy but the browser displays that the request to the server was interrupted while the page is loading

Comment: So the process still did not work end-to-end with OCSP disabled? This almost certainly means that your proxy loses data in transit. My suggestion would be comparing traffic captures between client<->proxy, and proxy<->server.

Comment: Roman, i see that the Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, and Hello Request all being sent in one single TLSv1.2 packet from the browser to the proxy, but immediately after this packet i also see another packet (TCP) whose flags are RST, ACK and a message when expanded saying Connection Reset with severity level warn & is marked as an acknowledgement packet to the previous (client key exchange) packet.

it is now clear that the browser is sending the client key exchange to proxy but the proxy is resetting the connection. but i am not sure why, & the code is the same for all this workflow

Comment: What is the traffic between proxy and upstream server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76409/discussion-between-saasira-and-romank).